# Continued fractions: why $[a_0; a_1, a_2] \neq [a_0; a_1, a_2, 0, 0, ....]$

Tags: definition, continued-fractions

It is my understanding that if a [continued fraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction) is finite, then it is typically written:
$$
  [a_0; a_1, a_2]_c = a_0 + \frac{1}{a_1 + \frac{1}{a_2}}
$$
(where subscript $c$ stands for "current definition") whereas if it is infinite, one writes it as:
$$
  [a_0; a_1, a_2, ...]_c = a_0 + \frac{1}{a_1 + \frac{1}{a_2 + \frac{1}{...}}}
$$

To me, however, **this ellipsis makes the definitions of finite and infinite continued fractions different**. Specifically, with this "definition", I think we have that:
$$
  [a_0; a_1, a_2, 0, 0, 0, ...]_c = [a_0; a_1, a_2 +1]_c
$$
because:
$$
  \frac{1}{0 + \frac{1}{0 + \frac{1}{...}}} = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{\frac{1}{...}}} = 1
$$

Hence my questions:

- Is this correct? I.e. do we have $[a_0; a_1, a_2, 0, 0, ...]_c = [a_0; a_1, a_2+1]_c$?
- Why not define continued fractions such that $[a_0; a_1, a_2]_p = [a_0; a_1, a_2, 0, 0, ...]_p$ (where $p$ stands for "proposed")? E.g. are there desirable properties that would not be valid with such a definition?

This would be equivalent to $[a_0; a_1, a_2]_p = [a_0; a_1, a_2-1]_c$ with the constraint that the last term in the "current" finite representation always be greater than 1. To expand this definition further, we would have:
$$
  [a_0; a_1, a_2]_p = a_0 + \frac{1}{a_1 + \frac{1}{a_2 + 1}}
$$
to be compared with the definition at the top of this post.

---

As far as I can see, such a definition would be beneficial. For example, it would eliminate the [ambiguity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stern%E2%80%93Brocot_tree#A_tree_of_continued_fractions) in the finite case:
$$
  [a_0; a_1, ..., a_{k-1}, 1]_c = [a_0; a_1, ..., a_{k-1}+1]_c
$$
which is typically "solved" by imposing $a_{k}\geq 2$. This would be implied with the proposed definition.

It seems to me that this is a "mistake" that has now been accepted, but perhaps I am missing something?